# Add a button in tableViewHeader like default iOS one

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController where I want to add a UIButton in the section header.

I saw in calendar app this button, and I wanted to know if this is part of a class I can reuse, or if I need to write my own class to add it.

[image: Button in tableView header in calendar app]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use your own custom class for this case. 
Because **UITableViewHeaderFooterView** does not containing any kind of buttons itself.
So, better go with your customClass.

Comment: is not a answer, its the comment plz move your answer to comment section

Comment: I'm a beginner to this community so i don't have enough reputation to add a comment to questions. plz bear with this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a xib file and create it class file.
Add your button and create its outlet.
Register your xib same in you viewDidLoad()

For example:

```
let headerNib = UINib(nibName: "yourNIBname", bundle: nil)
tableView.register(headerNib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifer")
```

Then add the following tableview delegate

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView {
        let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifer") as! youNIBClassName
        headerView.yourButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(hideAllTapped(withSender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return headerView
    }
```

You will get the action event in your hideAllTapped() function

```
@objc func hideAllTapped(withSender sender: UIButton) {
        // do your action
    }
```